# Spring JUnit Test load properties of file outside of src/test/resources

Tags: java, spring, junit

I want to load a properties file into Spring,but Spring cannot find the properties file with this XML.

The File is at `/MyProject/MyModule/testData/testProperties.properties`

The Test is at `/MyProject/MyModule/src/test/MyTest.java`

How to make Spring load from the correct path?

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>testData/testProperties.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `file:` prefix

```
<value>file:/MyProject/MyModule/testData/testProperties.properties</value>
```